# How to use GPath with variable?

Tags: variables, groovy, findall, xmlslurper, gpath

Let's say I have the following XML at hand

```
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse>
      <productOfferings>
        <productOffering>
          <id>some value</id>
        </productOffering>
      </productOfferings>
    </analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I also have the input XML in form of GPathResult after retrieving the file and parsing it:

```
inputXML = new XmlSlurper().parse(inputFile)
```

when I try to find the node like this:

```
inputXML."Body"."analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse"."productOfferings"."productOffering".depthFirst().findAll {it.value}
```

I get the required child "id"

however if I use a string that holds this text:

```
"Body"."analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse"."productOfferings"."productOffering"
```

and use it like so:

```
inputXML."${xPath}".depthFirst().findAll {it.value}
```

It doesn't work... 
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current attempt, Groovy is calling the [getProperty](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) method on the `inputXML` object with argument `"Body"."analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse"."productOfferings"."productOffering"`.

Since there is no XML child element with that specific name, nothing is found.

Instead, your aim is to dynamically chain the calls along the lines of this:

```
inputXML.getProperty('Body')
        .getProperty('analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse')
        .getProperty('productOfferings')
        .getProperty('productOffering')
        .depthFirst().findAll {it.value}
```

You could do this by creating a method that recursively creates this chaining, e.g.

```
def xPath = '"Body"."analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse"."productOfferings"."productOffering"'

def getProperties(gpathResult, dotProp) {
    def props = dotProp?.split(/\./)
    props.length <= 1 ? gpathResult : getProperties(gpathResult[props.head() - '"' - '"'], (props.tail().join('.')))
}

getProperties(inputXML, xPath).depthFirst().findAll {it.value}
```

Or you could use a full-fledged XPath library.

Comment: I am curious, though - this gets me a collection of strings eventually. what if I want to get the actual nodes in the XML so I can update them?

Comment: Your current code gets back a collection of `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren` representing the productOffering node and its parents.

Comment: Interesting approach, but would only work with the simplest `gpath` expressions, i.e. it wouldn't work with e.g. `A.B[1].C` or similar, would it?

Answer (score 3):

Possible to use [Eval.me](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html):

```
def inputXML = new XmlSlurper().parseText( '''<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse>
      <productOfferings>
        <productOffering>
          <id>some value</id>
        </productOffering>
      </productOfferings>
    </analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>''')

println inputXML."Body"."analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse"."productOfferings"."productOffering".depthFirst().findAll {it.value}

//use Eval.me groovy code evaluation
def gpath = ' XML."Body"."analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse"."productOfferings"."productOffering" '
println Eval.me( 'XML', inputXML, gpath ).depthFirst().findAll {it.value}

//or even like this:
gpath = ' XML."Body"."analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse"."productOfferings"."productOffering".depthFirst().findAll {it.value} '
println Eval.me( 'XML', inputXML, gpath )
```

Comment: but in this example `gpath` is a string and you can get it from any storage... could you provide more info what exactly is not working...

Comment: I actually found my problem - it was simple value mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a string or are you just looking for a way to store a path  to an element so that you don't have to type it again later?

```
String xml = '<Envelope><Body><analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse><productOfferings><productOffering><id>some value</id></productOffering></productOfferings></analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse></Body></Envelope>'
def Envelope = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
Closure takeMyPathFrom = {node -> node."Body"."analyzeEffectOfReplaceOfferResponse"."productOfferings"."productOffering"}
assert takeMyPathFrom(Envelope) == "some value"
```